# ¿Como usar CASE, IF con tipo de variable varchar y mostrar ordenado adicionando columna?

Tags: sql-server

Agradeceré su apoyo en lo siguiente, tengo una tabla en SQL Server como la que sigue. donde piden sacar a Personal x código que cumpla mas de una condición detallada (POR COLUMNAS).

Ejemplo cumpla codigo1 y codigo2 (G001+1) Y (GT01+1), y una columna final que al cumplir ambas condiciones, muestre ejemplo "CUMPLIO/NO CUMPLE", sin embargo al usar case me arroja incluso los que no poseen la condición,

NOTA; Los campos son Varchar y Date

TABLA ORIGEN

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CONSULTA:

```
SELECT
LOTE, MES, CODIGO,
Min(CASE WHEN ((CODIGO1='G001' AND COD2='1') )THEN FECHA ELSE NULL END)'CUMPLE1',
Min(CASE WHEN ((CODIGO1='GT01' AND COD2='1') )THEN FECHA ELSE NULL END)'CUMPLE2',
FROM
TABLA1
WHERE    FECHA>=01/12/2020
GROUP BY LOTE, MES, CODIGO
```

TABLA RESULTADO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se asume que si encuentra la primera condición, recién coloque la segunda (indistinto de que cumpla esta ultima) y se adicione una 3era columna según el resultado.

Sin embargo he tratado pero me arroja todos los datos colocando NULL en la mayoria ya que varios llevan diferentes codigos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He tratado de hacer una subconsulta dentro del case y me indica que no procede.
Agradeceré el apoyo o orientación

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! porque si tu pregunta es sobre sql server, pusiste como etiquetas, mysql y python? asi nadie que sepa sqlserver vera tu pregunta...

Comment: MySQL o SQL server? Pregunto porque la pregunta dice una cosa y las etiquetas, otra

Comment: Es en SQL Server, y de esta consulta se añadira otras condiciones (que cumpla luego 3 o 4 condiciones )

Comment: Entonces, podrias ser tan amable de arreglar las etiquetas usando el boton [edit]... digo.. no costaba nada ya que estas siguiendo la publicacion..

Comment: Hola, gracias por la recomendacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dudo mucho que la performance sea mejor que la respuesta de Roger, pero como has preguntado la posibilidad de no usar el `CASE` en la función de agregación, puedes probar construyendo 3 consultas e integrarlas: 1) Las filas que que cumple la primer condición 2) las que cumplen la segunda y 3) Todos. La idea sería algo así:

```
;WITH C1 AS (
    SELECT  LOTE, MES, CODIGO, MIN(FECHA) AS CUMPLE1
            FROM TABLA1
            WHERE FECHA > = '01/12/2020'
                AND CODIGO1 = 'G001' 
                AND COD2 = '1'
            GROUP BY LOTE, MES, CODIGO
),
C12 AS (
    SELECT  LOTE, MES, CODIGO, MIN(FECHA) AS CUMPLE2
            FROM TABLA1
            WHERE FECHA >= '01/12/2020'
                AND CODIGO1 = 'GT01' 
                AND COD2 = '1'
            GROUP BY LOTE, MES, CODIGO
)
SELECT  T.LOTE, 
        T.MES, 
        T.CODIGO,
        C1.CUMPLE1,
        C2.CUMPLE2,
        CASE WHEN C1.CUMPLE1 IS NOT NULL AND C2.CUMPLE2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'CUMPLIO' ELSE 'NO CUMPLE' END AS RESULTADO
        FROM TABLA1 T
        LEFT JOIN C1
            ON C1.LOTE = T.LOTE
            AND C1.MES = T.MES
            AND C1.CODIGO = T.CODIGO
        LEFT JOIN C2
            ON C2.LOTE = T.LOTE
            AND C2.MES = T.MES
            AND C2.CODIGO = T.CODIGO
        WHERE C1.CUMPLE1 IS NOT NULL 
              OR C2.CUMPLE2 IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY T.LOTE, T.MES, T.CODIGO, 
                 C1.CUMPLE1, C2.CUMPLE2
```

Usamos una [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) con dos subconsultas, con los datos de cada condición, luego unimos todos los casos con la tabla completa a modo de pivote. Incluso con un poco de trabajo usando un `full outer join` se podría obviar esta consulta pivote.

Comment: Hola Patricio, gracias por la recomendacion, estoy aprendiendo, y probare tambien tu sugerencia, lo comentare.en un par de dias

Comment: Hola Patricio, he probado la consulta y si da tambien los resultados. muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar tu consulta como sub consulta de otra que realice la discriminación entre si cumple o no cumple:

```
SELECT LOTE, MES, CODIGO, CUMPLE1, CUMPLE2,
CASE WHEN ((CUMPLE1 IS NOT NULL AND CUMPLE2 IS NOT NULL)) THEN 'CUMPLIO' ELSE 'NO CUMPLE' END as CUMPLE3
FROM (
   SELECT
   LOTE, MES, CODIGO,
   Min(CASE WHEN ((CODIGO1='G001' AND COD2='1')) THEN FECHA ELSE NULL END) as CUMPLE1,
   Min(CASE WHEN ((CODIGO1='GT01' AND COD2='1')) THEN FECHA ELSE NULL END) as CUMPLE2,
   FROM
   TABLA1
   WHERE    FECHA>=01/12/2020
   GROUP BY LOTE, MES, CODIGO
) a
--Si quieres que solo aparezcan los que cumplen alguna de las condiciones:
WHERE CUMPLE1 IS NOT NULL OR CUMPLE2 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hola Roger, la lógica me parece interesante gracias, sin embargo, el problema que poseo es que siempre ubica a todo código que no posee la condición en la columna CUMPLE1 yCUMPLE2, si tengo 100 codigos/usuarios, me muestra los 100 independiente de que solo 15 cumplan la condicion total o parcial.igual probare tu recomendacion, te comento. gracias nuevamente

Comment: @Aprendiz, he modificado la respuesta añadiendo una condición (`WHERE`) al final para que solo salgan aquellos que cumplen al menos una de las condiciones

Comment: Hola Roger, lo he tratado de armar segun indicas, sin embargo me arroja El identificador formado por varias partes lote, mes, codigo

Comment: @Aprendiz, he retocado un poco el código, puesto que no habia visto que era en SQL Server

Comment: Hola Roger, acabo de verificar mis errores en la codificación y si muestra los resultados, hare una muestra grande para confirmar al menos de 1 mes, Muchas Gracias, y sin incomodar, hay otro método en el que se pueda generar sin uso de CASE ya que se hace algo pesado la consulta (demora mucho tiempo)

Comment: Estoy verificando y esta cumpliendo, solo el tiempo de demora en procesar es algo largo.Bien Amigo Roger Gracias

Comment: He verificado y si arroja el resultado esperado, intento mejorarlo colocando en el primer CASE(CASE WHEN ((month(fecha)=12......) extrayendo el MES de la fecha, sin embargo me indica que El nombre de columna 'MES' no es válido.Use Month y tambien Format, en ningun caso permite NOTA:Fuera del case si resulta la extraccion

Comment: Disculpen, ya me di cuenta de mi error, ya que no habia incluido como nueva columna Mes